# Open modified files in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to have the git support in visual studio open the files that are modified and/or new?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tab in the visual studio under View Menu :

View -> Git Changes

You can find added and/or modified files, by clicking on modified files you can view which lines are modified.

Comment: Yes, seems I have to use that one instead of what I aimed for. To open an editor for every changed file.

Answer (score -1):

for this open git changes in Visual Studio.There

Comment: Did you check for similar answers first?